# create-react-app git pushing node_modules

Tags: git, reactjs, azure, gitignore, create-react-app

So I am trying to push my initial commit using the `create-react-app` from a local git build. My `.gitignore` looks like such:

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production


# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

And my directory looks like this:

[image]

Left the directory structure the same by default, so why is it uploaded `node_modules` as well?

**UPDATED INFO:**

So revised that in my git ignore, but it seemed to have still pushed the `node_modules'. My git root is theapp > build / node_modules / public / etc... if that helps.

I went ahead and allowed it, but at the end of my push with `git push azure master`, I got this now:

[image]

Additionally, within windows, my file explorer looks like this:

[image]

Further thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

`/node_modules` is looking at the root of your *computer*.

What you want is `node_modules/`.  Which looks for that directory relative to your current position.

Comment: thanks for the info, but is failing. Added additional info to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

After you fix your `.gitignore` file, the directory still remains in the history. To permanently remove `node_modules` from the history, see [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: I did a `rm -rf .git` and that removed the hidden git folder and therefore should have removed the history as well. Is that not correct? Actually, I did that, did a `git init` and also reset the upstream repo within Azure.

Comment: @Mark That works, too, if you want to start over from scratch