# node_modules commit issues in Azure with local git over and over

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service, node-modules

First and foremost, I am trying to have my azure app service host my `create-react-app` as well as use it to store my code, minus the node_modules. That said, I have started from scratch a few times after searching, asking here and elsewhere, but each time, when I go to push, somehow `node_modules` continues to persist in uploading itself.

My process has been:

`git init`, then `touch .gitignore`, with my `.gitignore` looking like:

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
node_modules

# production


# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
package-lock.json
```

Then I do a `git add .`, then add my remote, then a `git commit -m ""`, then a `git push azure master`, but regardless, "node_modules" continue to persist in being push. Why?

If I do a `git status`, you can see that it does not show the `node_modules` directory, so why does it continue to push it up? The image here shows the results of `git status`:

[image]

Again, I have done a complete reset 3-4 times with the issue being the same each and every time. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468847/create-react-app-git-pushing-node-modules) where I thought I found resolution through another post, but despite these actions, still the same results. Should I do something else?

**UPDATE:**

Tried per the first answer, and all looks fine, but then it starts with the `node_modules` again. You can see what happens here in the screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas what is going on here with this? This initial built using the `create-react-app` and it seems something is happening when it hits the default scripts or something. Further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, to be sure, ignoring a folder should end with a `/`

```
node_modules/
```

If the git status does not show that folder, you can check if it is ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- node_modules/a_file_within_node_modules
```

Second, make sure node_modules itself has no .git subfolder of its own.

Comment: thanks. Checked and did all you suggested, but still get same results. Updated intial post with more info hoping to get closer to resolution!

Comment: @Mark Is the check-ignore result empty?

Comment: here is what I get with it: `git check-ignore -v -- node_modules/accepts/index.js
.gitignore:4:node_modules/      node_modules/accepts/index.js` Though I am not sure if that is good or what. There are no git files within the `node_modules` folder either.

Comment: At least that folder is not added to the repo

Comment: If that one isn't being added, then in that theory, none of them should be added if all are added to the `.gitignore`, right? In doing this, is it possible that the `react-scripts` within the `package.json` is doing something to the `git push....`?

Comment: @Mark Yes, it is possible for the node_modules to be generated, following the specification in package.json. In other words, its presence on the remote side would not be related to git itself.

Comment: So then still no ideas on resolution?

Comment: @Mark No. But if that folder is generate instead of being pushed, that would explain what you see.